# Preserve factor levels for facet grid bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have data that has several independent variables and one dependent variable, and occurs over several categories of events. I want to put together a facet grid of bar charts, one for each independent variable and category combination, x-axes ordered correctly.

In order to make the independent variables categorical to be the x-axis of the bar charg, I have cut each one and summarized it in the correct way. I do similar to the following code snippet for each of my independent variables and convert them to a long format.

`alldata` is a wide data table that has every observation and category listed.

```
var1category = alldata%>%
mutate(var1=cut(alldata$var1,breaks=c(min(alldata$var1),500,1000,1500,2000,max(alldata$var1)),labels=c("<500","500-1000","1000-1500","1500-2000",">2000"),ordered_result=TRUE))%>%
group_by(var1,category)%>%summarize(dv=mean(dv))%>%
gather(xvar,value,var1)
```

Then I call `longdata=bind_rows(var1category,var2category,...)`, which puts the data into a plottable format.

```
ggplot(longdata,aes(x=value,y=dv))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+facet_grid(category~xvar,scales="free")
```

This results in plots with mis-ordered x-axes.

[image]

Following some other advice I found on SO, I added `%>%mutate(value = factor(value, levels=unique(value)))` to my definitions of `var1category`, but then since the levels of the different variables are not equivalent, `bind_rows` fails.

Is there a way to make my data long while preserving the order of the individual factors? Alternatively, I'd be happy to have to call ggplot several times as long as I could align the plots in a way similar to a facet grid with labelled categories/IVs.

Comment: You need `fct_relevel` from forcats package.

Comment: (a) Can you share an illustrative sample of `alldata`? Preferably using `dput` so it is copy/pasteable? (b) Don't use `$` inside `dplyr` functions, it will mess up the grouping. Just use the column names.

Comment: @JilberUrbina, that solves the issue. Thanks!